# Using a variable in a selector in LESS

Tags: less

I have a variable `@index` and I want to output a selector so that when `@index` is `3`, the selector is `[data-sth="3"]`.

Longer example:

```
@index: 3;
/* selector here */ {
    color: red;
}
```

Desired output:

```
[data-sth="3"] {
    color: red;
}
```

I've tried a few things, but haven't managed to get anything that works, yet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [Variable Interpolation](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation). I.e.:

```
[data-sth="@{index}"] {
    color: red;
}
```

---

*Original answer (Less versions before 1.40):*

> The following code should work:
>
> `(~'[data-sth="@{index}"]') {
>       color: red;
>   }`
>
> The `~` removes the quotation marks.